# InstantRails 2.0 upgrade Rails to 2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am developing with Rails on Windows versions. IR 2.0 comes with Rails 2.0.
What is the correct way to upgrade the rails (and Ruby) to the latest version?

Rails 2.3
Ruby  1.9

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about upgrading ruby (since I haven't done it myself) but rails can be upgraded just like any other gem:

```
gem update rails
```

(right-click on the InstantRails icon->Rails Applications->OpenRuby Console Window)

Comment: I tried doing that few times and there are issues with the ruby version and other gems. I think I need to update the Ruby gem to 1.9 but whatever I did will not work.
On some blogs I found that you need to remove ruby & rails gems and install again using the latest version. 
Thanks again.

Comment: Hmmm... I'm running Ruby 1.8.6 and don't remember having any problems upgrading. Admittedly, I've had InstantRails installed for >6 months so maybe I had to fix something and don't remember. 
The only problems I've had are related to gems with native extensions not building. Also, you might check whether all your gems are compatible with Ruby 1.9... I still have my doubts.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty late but you can fix that with the following command:

gem update --system --source http://production.s3.rubygems.org

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own problem by using NetBeans 6.7.1. It has Rails 2.3.2 built in and webrick.I had to install MySQL server locally. If you run it on Vista you need to run it in Admin mode to get all the gems and updates.